# How to prove there's an upper bound on a series

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

There's a series as following.
$$
\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}} + \cdots
$$
Is there any way I can find the upper bound to prove the limit exist?
I've tried to write down the formula of this series as following:
$$
x_n = \sqrt{3 + x_{n - 1}}
$$
but still find no way to modify it to get to the upper bound.

Comment: More similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/115501

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Show inductively that all the terms are bounded by $$\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$$